# Sorting array not sorting

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I must set an array to accept 7 numbers from the user, then send the array to be sorted in ascending order. the array is not being sorted and its just given the values back the exact way they were entered.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class arraySorted {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int [] enterednumbers = new int[7];


    System.out.println("Enter 7 numbers in any order");
    for( int i =0; i < enterednumbers.length; i++) {
    enterednumbers[i] = in.nextInt();


    }

    for (int d = 0; d < enterednumbers.length; d++) {
        System.out.print(enterednumbers[d] + " ");
    }

}
public static void sort(int enterednumbers[]) {
    int n = 7;
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <n; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j<n; j++) {
            if (enterednumbers[i] > enterednumbers[j]) {
                temp = enterednumbers[i];
                enterednumbers[i] = enterednumbers[j];
                enterednumbers[j] = temp;

            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

The input read as:

Enter 7 numbers in any order
8
4
8
9
7
5
7

than the output is:
8 4 8 9 7 5 7

Comment: where are you sorting the array?

Comment: I was trying to send it to the public static void sort. Did I not do this step correctly?

Comment: You did not.  Simply defining a method doesn't mean it will ever get run. You need to actually invoke it somewhere in your code.

Comment: don't implement  your own sorting. use the built in methods. for arrays it's https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Comment: Don't hardcode `n=7` in your sort method.  Use `enterednumbers.length` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the function to sort the values. Currently you are not calling the function. You are taking the input and displaying it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class arraySorted {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] enterednumbers = new int[7];

        System.out.println("Enter 7 numbers in any order");
        for (int i = 0; i < enterednumbers.length; i++) {
            enterednumbers[i] = in.nextInt();

        }
        sort(enterednumbers);//Function Call

        for (int d = 0; d < enterednumbers.length; d++) {
            System.out.print(enterednumbers[d] + " ");
        }

    }

    public static void sort(int enterednumbers[]) {
        int n = 7;
        int temp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                if (enterednumbers[i] > enterednumbers[j]) {
                    temp = enterednumbers[i];
                    enterednumbers[i] = enterednumbers[j];
                    enterednumbers[j] = temp;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You wrote a function for sorting, but you haven't called it anywhere in main. Call it before you enter the loop to print the array.

Edit: Incase you don't know how to do this, simply add

```
sort(enterednumbers);
```

before you enter the loop to print the values, but after the loop to insert the values. Ofcourse, you can use built in Array function .sort(), but writing sorting manually the way you are doing is actually a pretty good learning exercise.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the method sort before showing on console. Just that